# Is it possible to create a macro like that with AHK?

Tags: command-line, macros, autohotkey

I'm something like a GM in a MMORPG game. Our job is reporting people who using cheat and sending them to jail. But leaving that jail zone is not really hard so we have to send them again and again. I have a loooong nickname list (I have about 400 nicknames to report repeatly) so It's really boring.

What i wanna ask is, I don't know anything about AHK. If that kind of macro is possible, I'll do a loooong research to create that macro. But if It's not possible, I'm not even gonna try.

What i need is; The Macro will press "enter" to activate chat mode. Then will write "/report -cheater nickname-" and remember there's 400+ nicknames exist so I need to repeat the macro for different nicknames. After it write "/report -cheater nickname-" Macro will press enter. Then a little chat box will pop-up. Macro will click to the box, will write the report reason, then click confirm. then another chat box will pop-up to say something like "your report is received." And macro will click to confirm for that too. And will do it for 400+ nicknames with 400+ different reasons. Is that actually possible to do? Just wondering that. Not asking you to creating this macro. If you answer that, I'll try to make it myself :D

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds possible, where is the list of names and reasons coming from? The `Send` & `ControlClick` commands should do most of that. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm

Answer (score 0):

This script is to perform a series of searches on Google. The search strings are stored in a text file and read into an array, they are then executed one by one, based on hitting the {Tab} key (you can make this repeat automatically).

When the script is interrupted, you can start it again and give it a (new) starting number, or tell it to start from 1 again.

Not exactly what you were looking for, but it gives you a lot of starting points.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
TempDir = C:\Temp
Menu, Tray, Icon , %A_AhkPath%, 2, 1
TrayTip, JobSearch, Started, 1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
TextCounter = 0
Return

+Launch_App1::
Run, Notepad %TempDir%\Google.txt
Return

Launch_App1:: ; vacatures Job Search
+CapsLock::
Restart:
MouseGetPos, XPos2, YPos2
XPos3 := 50
YPos3 := 100
IniRead, TextCounter, %TempDir%\GoogleCounter.ini, Counter, Nr

ArrayCount = 0
Loop, Read, %TempDir%\Google.txt   ; This loop retrieves each line from the file, one at a time.
{
    ArrayCount += 1  ; Keep track of how many items are in the array.
    Array%ArrayCount% := A_LoopReadLine  ; Store this line in the next array element.
}
MaxSearchCount = %ArrayCount%
TextCounter += 1
If (TextCounter > 1)
InputBox, TextCounter , Start, Number (1..%MaxSearchCount%),,,,,,,10,%TextCounter%  ; InputBox, OutputVar [, Title, Prompt, HIDE, Width, Height, X, Y, Font, Timeout, Default]
TextCounter += 0
IniWrite, %TextCounter%, %TempDir%\GoogleCounter.ini, Counter, Nr
SearchText:=Array%TextCounter%
MouseClick, left
gosub, SendNewSearch
Return

;=======================================================================================================================================
Browser_Favorites:: ; Search for next Vacature string (Vacatures)
CapsLock::
If (TextCounter = 0) ; Restart with previous script if Textcounter is set to 0
{
    GoSub,  Restart
    Exit
}
IniRead, TextCounter, %TempDir%\GoogleCounter.ini, Counter, Nr
TextCounter += 1
IniWrite, %TextCounter%, %TempDir%\GoogleCounter.ini, Counter, Nr
SearchText:=Array%TextCounter%
If (SearchText = "")
{
    TextCounter := 0
    IniWrite, %TextCounter%, %TempDir%\GoogleCounter.ini, Counter, Nr
    Send, ^{F4}
    SplashTextOff
    ExitApp
}

Sleep, 200
Send, {Home 2}
Sleep, 700
Send, {WheelUp 10}
Sleep, 400
gosub, SendNewSearch
Exit

SendNewSearch:
    MouseGetPos, XPos3 ,YPos3 
    SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    IfWinActive, Chrome
    {
    while (A_Cursor = "AppStarting")
        Sleep, 200 ; Continue

    Sleep, 100
    SplashTextOff
    MouseClick, left, %XPos2%,%YPos2%
    WinGetTitle, this_title, A
    IfInString, this_title, Google
    {
        Send, {Home}+{End}{DEL}%SearchText%{Enter}
    }
    ToolTip, Waiting....
    DisplayText = Nr%TextCounter%  %SearchText%
    Sleep, 500
    SplashTextOn, 200, 0,%DisplayText%
    WinMove, %DisplayText%, , 800, 25
    ToolTip
    ;MouseMove,(50),(500)
    MouseMove,%XPos3%,%YPos3%
    ClipBoard = %SearchText%
    }
Exit
Exit

+Browser_Favorites::
run, %TempDir%\Google.txt
Return
```

Comment: 1. The best solution is to address the root cause. i.e. make the system more robust and prevent "power wars" because the users can write scipts to re-enable their accounts too. I assume that you don't have 400 reasons, but only a hand-full. I would create one txt file with the users-ID's + Reason-ID and a second file with the reason-ID and the expanded text for that reason. This way you don't have to repeat the reason text 400 times and you only need to modify the reason text once if something changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do. You can create two txt files which have list of +400 user names and +400 different reasons. Macro can read lines one by one and can makes all things, what you want, more than 400 times.

You will need [this loop](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Arrays.htm) for writing lines from txt file to an array, a loop in a [function](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm) for checking expected color at the specified pixel with `PixelGetColor` (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelGetColor.htm) for detecting buttons. You may also use `PixelGetColor` command or AutoIt3 Window Spy, which will be installed with [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey), to see colors of buttons. Finally you can start to code from here (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/).

PS. Sorry, site did not allow me to use more than 2 hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to write a script that types enter, then a list of characters then enter again?

Something quite simple you could do would be to create a .txt file that includes everything you want it to type (excluding enters, except between lines), and create a macro like this:

```
#n::
Loop, Read, inputFile.txt
{
    Send {Enter}%A_LoopReadLine%{Enter}
}
return
```

Basically you run the macro and open the game to the point that you can start typing enter, character information, enter, but press the windows key and the 'n' key.  The macro would then loop through each line of 'inputFile.txt' and stimulate typing an enter, the line, and then an enter.